# Add header for different blocks Angular 1

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have recently started learning Angular 1, I have gotten ng-repeat to work with the elements I need. However, I want to add a title to each block and I'm finding this difficult.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div class="js-box"  ng-repeat="x in boxs">
        <p> {{x}} </p>
    <div class="tagger" ng-repeat="x in records">
            <div class="codeSnippet">
            {{x.Elem}}
        </div>
        <div class="taggerDescription">
        <p>
            {{x.Description}}
        </p>
        </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/znerrjg4/1/

What is currently happening is, the title is being repeated (Block 1, Block 2), but I don't want the rest to be repeated, as you see Elem 1 - Elem 4 is also repeated in block 2, but I would like Elem 1 - Elem 4 to be in Block 1, and then Elem 5 - Elem 8 to be in Block 2.

I hope that makes sense
Please let me know if you need more information.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`<div class="js-box"  ng-repeat="x in boxs">
        <p> {{x}} </p>
    <div class="tagger" ng-repeat="x in records">`

When you say `x in boxs` and then `x in records` you are "confusing" angular. Change one of those `x` to something else.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for your comment. I understand how this could be seen as confusing, I've changed the "x in boxs" to "y in boxes", and I am still seeing the same issue. https://jsfiddle.net/znerrjg4/2/

Thanks